# Laravel proper writing of middleware group

Tags: php, laravel

**I’m not sure if I wrote the code correctly so I want someone to help me**

**I wrote it like this but I'm not sure if it works normally I don't know if it will be able to cause a bug**

**Web.php**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {

    Route::resource('categories','CategoriesController');

    Route::resource('posts','PostsController')->middleware(['auth','verifyCategoriesCount']);

    Route::get('trashed-posts', 'PostsController@trashed')->name('trashed-posts.index');

    Route::put('restore-post/{post}','PostsController@restore')->name('restore-posts');

});
```

**verifyCategoriesCount**

```
   public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Category::all()->count() === 0){
            session()->flash('error','You need to add categories to be able to create a post');

            return redirect(route('categories.create'));
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

**I'm wondering if I wrote these middleware groups correctly**

**If I didn't write nicely, tell me what I'm doing wrong**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will work without any problems.

`Route::resource('posts','PostsController')->middleware(['auth','verifyCategoriesCount']);`

^ You should remove the `auth` middleware from there, because it is already in the `Route::group` above.

Comment: I removed 'auth' and left only ('verifyCategoriesCount') so that the check could work for posts

Comment: Right! If i remember right, if you only have 1 middleware, you can even remove the array [] from it. Like `middleware('auth')` instead of `middleware(['auth'])`.

Comment: I tried and so but then it will not work (verifyCategoriesCount) because by some miracle it is not called @Furkan

Comment: That's strange, i just checked the docs and it should work. Can you edit your post and add your current code (where your middleware doesn't get called)?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's my fault I didn't understand your message but now everything is fine

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine, can you further elaborate what is the issue are you facing.You can group middleware as following.

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {

    //Group Routes here

});
```

OR

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {

    //Group Routes here

});
```

Comment: I have tried both ways and both ways are neat
Thanks for helping